Error: Unable to resolve module fs from {Root Floder}\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\app\lifecycle.js:
{Root Floder}\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\app\lifecycle.js:

  19 | Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
  20 | exports.FIREBASE_CONFIG_VAR = exports.deleteApp = exports.getApps = exports.getApp = exports.initializeApp = exports.defaultAppStore = exports.AppStore = void 0;
> 21 | const fs = require("fs");
     |                     ^
  22 | const validator = require("../utils/validator");
  23 | const error_1 = require("../utils/error");
  24 | const credential_internal_1 = require("./credential-internal");



firebaseadmin.js
 import admin from 'firebase-admin';
import serviceAccount from './seviceaccount.json';

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: 'https://PROJECT ID(here I am using my app id).firebaseio.com',
});
export default admin;


How can I use Firebase Admin in my code to send notifications to users through my app?

What is the process for integrating Firebase Admin into my app's code to enable sending notifications to users?

Can you provide an example of how to use Firebase Admin in my app's code to send notifications to users?(In React-native code)


